# Preflight request handler arc.codes

Tags: node.js, cors, httprequest, preflight, architect

I'm running into a weird error with cors when doing a request from a react page to my back end that uses [arc.codes](https://arc.codes/docs/en/guides/get-started/quickstart) framework to run.
This is the complete error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3333/api/endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

**My front-end code that made the request is the following:**

```
const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'Bearer token'
        },
    };
const response = yield call( fetchJSON, `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/contractormonths`, options );
```

**Back end code that processes the requests:**

.arc manifest file:

```
@app
my-app

@http
get /api/contractormonths
```

index.js file at /get-api-contractormonths

```
const arc = require('@architect/functions');
const { authorization } = require('@architect/shared/oauth');

async function route(request){
  return {
      cors: true,
      json: {'message':'Hello world!'}
  };
}

exports.handler = arc.http.async(authorization, route);
```

*Authorization function also returns an object with a property cors: true*

**What I've already tried and learned:**

- I think the request doesn't get to the GET handler function in the back
- When I removed the auth middleware (In the back) and the auth header (In the front) it works!
- This is probably related to the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) made by the browser (When it's a simple GET with no Headers it doesn't send the preflight request but it does when using the auth header)
- The *preflight request* is sending an OPTIONS request to my backend, I can confirm this because adding the OPTIONS request handler in my backend gets the requests instead of the GET handler

What can I do to handle these preflights requests in my back-end? Do I have to write an OPTIONS request handler to all of my current endpoints? Is there a way to disable the preflight request? Is it OK to disable the preflight request? Am I missing another important thing and overcomplicating this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code for your `authorization` function but that is where the root of the problem lies. You mentioned in your question that:

> Authorization function also returns an object with a property cors: true

but you don't actually want to return an object from this function unless you are failing the authentication step.

An example authorization method could look like this:

```
module.exports = async function auth (req, res, next) {
  // Do the OAuth Dance
  const oauth = oauthDance()
  if (!oauth.authenticated) {
    return {
      status: 401,
        json: { errors: [ 'authorization_failed' ] }
    }
  } else {
    // Oauth succeeded so let's add the token to the request
    // for the next function in the chain
    req.token = oauth.token
    next()
  }
}
```

That's some pretty contrived pseudo code but my suspicion is the `return` from your `authorization` method is short circuiting the chain and that's why the preflight check fails. Using `next()` to continue on to the next function in the chain should fix your issue.

Comment: You're right, the problem was in the authorization function, what I was trying to say with "Authorization function also returns an object with a property cors: true" is that when the authorization middleware fails I also return an object with cors: true. But in the end some unhandled exception was occurring in the authorization function so the "next" function was never called.